# Firefox the website editor?

Tags: firefox

There are a lot of [webdeveloper addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/collections/mozilla/webdeveloper/) available, for Firefox, like [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firebug/). Is there a html editor addon for Firefox that I can use to edit my website, viewing the edits real-time (using localhost or via ftp?) and saving the edits (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)?

I am currently using firebug and it would save a lot of time if I could save the (local) `.html` file using a firebug like addon! (or firebug itself?)

I Found a [firebug addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefile/) to save. Css files... now just need one to save html, and I am good to go!

Answer (score 0):

You can use web console. It is not an Add-on but it allows you to edit HTML, CSS, Java Script, and Etc.

**To Use It**

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> And Select HTML, CSS, Or Script Tab To Edit